# Django Admin, modify/customize the names in the select box of a manytomany field

Tags: django, django-admin

I have 2 models Category and Product. Category has a FK to itself, and Product a FK to Companies.

```
class Product(Meta):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')

 class Category(SEO, MetaData):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='parent category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In Django Admin in Product Create/Edit Page I need to select the Categories for Parent.

At this moment is just a long select box, with the names of Categories. I want to introduce the all path of the category-subcategory.

Ex:

```
Now: Category A Name
Need: Category Parent Name :: SubCategory Parent Name :: Category A Name
```

I don't want to modify `def __str__` because is used also in other places.

Comment: you can use `__str__` method to set the name you want to show.

Comment: @ In the post I wrote: "I don't want to modify def str because is used also in other places."

Comment: Ahh...that's my fault

Comment: Have you looked into django-mptt? It might be a good solution for this. See https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html

Comment: @AdamTaylor - I just want to know how to modify in admin the select box, for the tree structure I use enumerated path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom `ModelForm` like this:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'  # It's actually best to list the fields out as per Two Scoops of Django

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['categories'].label_from_instance = \
            lambda obj: obj.enumerated_path
```

Replace `enumerated_path` with whatever the `Product` model's property/method is named. Don't forget to use the form in your `ModelAdmin` by adding `form = ProductForm`.